# How can I suppress "What if" text being written to the console

Tags: powershell

I commonly use `SupportsShouldProcess` in my PowerShell functions along with `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess()` so I can sanity-check what a script is going to do. Generally I only implement this around actions that will change the environment, e.g. **Add-**, **New-**, **Set-** cmdlets, etc. In some cases I also want to bypass **Get-** cmdlets when running a script with the `-WhatIf` switch. For example:

I have a script that fingerprints all files in a folder using `Get-FileHash` before *doing something* to each file. In this example there are 10k+ files with an average size of 100MB or more and I don't want to spend time actually fingerprinting the files when I use `-WhatIf`. I cannot wrap the whole operation is just one `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("All Files","Get-FileHash")` block.

The effect of running `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess()` for each item in a loop is that I dump thousands of lines of "What if:" text back to the console.

**Question**: Is there a way to use `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess()` so it does **not** write to the console? If not, what workarounds might people use?

---

**Example code**

While I think the question works just in an abstract sense, this is a pretty practical forum so here is a simple example of the task I referred to above:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path <ReallyBigFolder>

foreach($File in $Files){
  $Action = Get-MyAction -Filename -$File.Fullname

  # Take hash of file
  $Hash = Get-FileHash -Path -$File.Fullname

  # Keep audit happy
  Write-Audit -Action $Action -Hash $Hash

  switch($Action){
    "Retain" {
      # do nothing
      break
    }

    "Remove" {
      if($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($File.Fullname,"Remove-Item")){
        Remove-Item $File.Fullname
      }
      break
    }

    default { # barf }
  }
}
```

Assume that 95% of the files will be kept, so in this example we "only" get 500 lines of WhatIf output on the screen, but spend time hashing files and writing audit logs (assume the latter is calling a REST API or something else that is slow over multiple iterations).

If I put the `Get-FileHash` and `Write-Audit` cmdlets in a `ShouldProcess()` block then I save time but get 10k or more lines written to screen.

I'm sure this example (and indeed my real code) could be restructured to keep the output under control, or I can just ignore the verbosity of WhatIf, but it happens that today I wondered if I could suppress the output...

Comment: Why can't you "wrap the whole operation in just one block"?

Comment: I take a FileHash for auditing purposes and then decide to action (move/delete/keep/etc.) each file based on certain criteria. I am using -WhatIf to be sure that the script will perform the correct action, but when running in this mode I don't really need the hash. If just wrapped the whole foreach loop in `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess()` I wouldn't see what would happen to each file.

Comment: To some extent this particular example is just to flesh out the question. I'd like to work this out regardless of the particular script I'm working on. This isn't the first time `-WhatIf` has spewed itself all over my console.

Comment: Hm, it seems like that's `-WhatIf` is supposed to do though. How can you "see what would happen to each file" without it telling you on the console, for each file, what would happen? Do you want a summary?

Comment: At the risk of getting away from the question in its academic sense, I have added some sample code to chew over.

Comment: Based on the sample code and what else you wrote, it looks like Martin's solution (or checking `$WhatIfPreference` as I commented) would be the best route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt you can supress the `ShouldProcess` output. As a workaround, you can check whether the `-whatif` parameter is present in the `$PSBoundParameters`:

```
if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('WhatIf'))
{
   # do something here without
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I might need to extend this answer to work for *implicit* setting of the WhatIf switch as well.

Comment: @CharlieJoynt I think this same approach would work for implicit whatif by just checking the value of `$WhatifPreference` directly.

Answer (score 2):

As an extension to the answer from @martin-brandl, here is how you might check for *implicit* use of the `WhatIf` switch:

```
if(((Get-PSCallStack).InvocationInfo.BoundParameters.ContainsKey("WhatIf")) `
    -and ((Get-PSCallStack).InvocationInfo.BoundParameters.WhatIf -eq $true))
{
  # don't do whatever you might have done
}
```

That is: check the call stack to see whether `-WhatIf` was supplied as a parameter anywhere, and verify that someone didn't negate it with `-WhatIf:$false`.

Maybe the comment on Martin's answer from @briantist about using `$WhatIfPreference` is easier though!

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm interpreting your question, it seems like you're not quite implementing `-WhatIf` correctly in this instance. `-WhatIf` should ensure nothing is changed. If you want to just to skip the fingerprinting but still *do something to each file* then you should implement your own switch like `-NoFingerprint` and use the value of that.

You should continue implementing `-WhatIf`, which will not process the files at all (in which case it may make sense to keep outputting all the lines).

Answer (score 0):

I had a parallel situation, where I wanted to write to a log file even when -WhatIf was supplied.

You could record the state of -WhatIf, turn it off temporarily, manually control the action you want to perform, then restore the original state of -WhatIf:

```
$MyWhatIf= $WhatIfPreference
$WhatIfPreference= $False
If (! $MyWhatIf) { Do-YourThing }
$WhatIfPreference= $MyWhatIf
```